# Why 'are' used in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> Carla: I thought you ... a healthy guy!
>
> A: were
>
> B: are

I encountered this question on an online quiz. I choose A, but the answer key is B. I'm wondering why A is incorrect?

Comment: This native speaker would have picked answer A also.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this online quiz? Reported thought generally backshifts, so *were* would be the most correct answer here.

Comment: Also, verb generally tenses typically agree with each other: (1) ***thought*** *you* ***were*** and (2) ***think*** *you* ***are***.

Comment: @choster It's the Wall street English site in Chinese. I'm afraid that if you don't know Chinese, you might not be  able to get into the quiz.

Comment: *Either could be correct*.  As a native speaker, I would choose "A" most of the time. But you could create a situation where the **context** suggests the present tense "are".  This is one **danger of online quizzes** --- they may not be written by native speakers, and they may not provide enough context to establish which answer is 100% correct.  The quiz writer may just say, "pick the *best* answer".  It depends on the situation: which situation the quiz writer thinks is most common may not be the same as what *you* think is the most common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Either could be correct.

### "Were" is most often correct.

In most cases, as user @Jason Bassford said in the comments, you will make the tenses match:

> A. I **thought** you **were** a healthy guy.
>
> X. I **think** you **are** a healthy guy.

In the context of an online quiz: as a native speaker, I would select "(A)" but there could be exceptions.

### "Are" can also be correct.

You could create a situation where "thought" was in the past tense and **being a healthy guy** needs to be in the present tense to show it is a *continuous action*.

Imagine Carla is a doctor.  She is meeting with a patient Bob in the afternoon.  Earlier that day, Carla met with the other doctors on her team to discuss Bob's case.

> Dr. Carla says, "All the doctors met this morning to discuss your case."
>
> Bob says, "What did they think? Am I cured?"
>
> Dr. Carla says,
>
> "Dr. White thought your test results are inconclusive.
>
> "Dr. Black thought you are almost cured.
>
> "Dr. Brown thought you are making good progress.
>
> "I thought you are a healthy guy."

In each of these sentences, either "are" or "were" should be acceptable ---- Dr. Carla would use **are** if she wants to emphasize that Bob's condition is an ongoing matter (it hasn't changed from the morning until now), or "were" if she wants to emphasize what the test results were showing *at that time.*

English is complicated, and there are often exceptions.

Comment: @whiskyechief  i think this type of questions should not be asked in the competitive exams they are still following prescriptive grammar